# Display: inline not working

Tags: css, list, menu, inline, navbar

bit of a noob here. Just need some help getting this menu to be in-line. It's currently displaying as a vertical list. Here's the relevant code:

```
#background #header #nav {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
}
#background #header #nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: inline;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    color: #40c8f4;
}

#background #header #nav ul li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40C8F4;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    }
#background #header #nav ul li .scroll {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40c8f4;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle will be nice. OR can u pls paste your html also.

Comment: `li` elements are block-level. You'll need to specify `display: inline` for those, too.

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure also.

Answer (score 1):

Make inline for li element :-

```
#background #header #nav ul li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40C8F4;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    display:inline ;
}
```

This will work

Comment: Never use "!important". It's a bad practice

Comment: Do agree, but can you please try without !important;, I think that will work too and if it does work and please remove my down vote

#background #header #nav ul li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40C8F4;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    display:inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
#background #header #nav ul li{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40C8F4;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your css but random HTML,  [**here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pE7g/1/)

Since you are using `inline`, i'll suggest using `inline-block` on `div`s, beacuse, this way, there default `display` property is not compromised and also you get `inline` features.

`div`'s are bye default `display:block` level elements

**CSS**

```
  #background #header #nav {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    display: inline-block;  /* add this */
}
#background #header #nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: inline;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    color: #40c8f4;

}
#background #header #nav ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40C8F4;
    font-color: #40C8F4;
    display: inline-block;/* add this */

}
#background #header #nav ul li .scroll {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40c8f4;
    display: inline-block;
}
```